# wifi state return false even it is connected

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am check phone wifi state in onStart of the app, but even if it connected it return false, I already tried many things but did not work

here is what I am doing

```
@Override protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    onStartStates();
 }
```

onStartStates() method

```
 private void onStartStates(){

   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo net = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    Log.d(TAG, "Wifi State 1"+net.isConnected());
    Log.d(TAG, "Wifi State 2"+getCurrentSsid(esActivity.this));
}
```

getCurrentSsid() method

```
 public static String getCurrentSsid(Context context) {
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = getCurrentWifiInfo(context);
    if (wifiInfo != null) {
        return wifiInfo.getSSID();
    }
    return null;
}

public static WifiInfo getCurrentWifiInfo(Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        return wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    }

    return null;
}
```

both method return false, even I switch wifi On just starting my app...any idea

Comment: Try moving your code from onStart() to onCreateView(). A lot of times the metods to check statuses and things like that are not available the earlier part on activity life cycles.

Comment: did you added proper persmissions in manifest ??

Comment: yes I have all permission required for this purpose

Comment: I tried moving it to onCreate as well, but the same

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method to detect if the device has network connectivity.
getting current active network might help you.

```
/**
 * Check for <code>TYPE_WIFI</code> and <code>TYPE_MOBILE</code> connection
 * using <code>isConnected()</code> Checks for generic Exceptions and writes
 * them to LogCat as <code>CheckConnectivity Exception</code>. Make sure
 * AndroidManifest.xml has appropriate permissions.
 * 
 * @param con
 *            Application context
 * @return Boolean
 */
public static boolean hasConnectivity(Context con)
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo         wifiInfo;
    NetworkInfo mobileInfo;
    try
    {
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean serviceAvailable = (netInfo!=null && netInfo.isConnected())? true:false;

        wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        mobileInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (wifiInfo.isConnected() || mobileInfo.isConnected() || serviceAvailable) 
        { 
            Logger.info(TAG + " : " + true);
            return true; 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.info(TAG + ": hasConnectivity: Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Logger.error(TAG + " : " + false);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's almost the same but I also check for current active network


NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();


Give it try and come back to me.

Comment: it returns false ...still